# Can't Install Avahi

Tags: snap, avahi

I am trying to install avahi for a class. I am running ubuntu 19.10. When I use the command "sudo snap install avahi" I get a series of changing lines, then it terminates with the following text:

```
(base) #######@#######:~$ sudo snap install avahi
[sudo] password for #######: 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- restart of [avahi.daemon] (# systemctl restart snap.avahi.daemon.service
Job for snap.avahi.daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status snap.avahi.daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
)
- restart of [avahi.daemon] (exit status 1)
(base) #######@#######:~$
```

I have restarted my system. I have run "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade" to make sure everything else was up to date. The grad student in the class that I need this for is baffled. Of note, the class - in learning linux on the raspberry pis we're trying to SSH into - is set up to support windows and mac laptops - I'm the only one in class running a linux distribution. I really, really, really don't want to work in windows, and it seems kind of silly, frankly.

Comment: Did you "`See "systemctl status snap.avahi.daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`"?
)

Comment: I did, and they were incomprehensible to me, but I can certainly see where they would be relevant here. I will edit my question and add them shortly.